# Find nearest value from a nested list to a given value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a nested list like `[[0,1,2],[9,5,3],[7,0,2]]` and a given value `4` how can I get the list that has the closest value to the given value? I saw using `min()` might helps but I not sure how does it work. Is this the only way to do it or does it has any alternatives?

Expected output :
`[9,5,3]`

Comment: what is expected output in this case? I guess - [9, 5, 3]. What if 5 and 3 are in different sub-list?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your expected output, _code_ for what you've tried so far expected output, and what went wrong with your attempts, to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can indeed use `min()` but with a custom key function:

```
>>> lst = [[0,1,2],[9,5,3],[7,0,2]]
>>> v = 4
>>> min(lst, key = lambda x: min(abs(i-v) for i in x))
[9, 5, 3]
```

Let's break that down a bit:

```
>>> [min(abs(i-v) for i in x) for x in lst]
[2, 1, 2]
>>> [[abs(i-v) for i in x] for x in lst]
[[4, 3, 2], [5, 1, 1], [3, 4, 2]]
```

If there's a tie (i.e. joint minimum) then `min()` returns the first instance

Comment: This is an elegant solution.

Comment: could you further explain why iterating over x is necessary? I'm new to python actually.

Comment: @Unknown You have to inspect every value of every sub-list to identity the minimum difference. If you're new to python, you might want to try writing it out as a nested `for` loop, e.g. `for sublist in lst: for item in sublist:` etc.